# Ice Cream Shop Calculations

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on this project for the past few days, and I've almost finished it. I am running into 2 problems that no matter what I seem to do, I can't fix them. The first is that the calculations are incorrect, for example when I select a flavour that costs .75 with 2 toppings and nuts the total should come out to 3.60 but it comes out to 2.10. I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the nested if statements but im not sure where. Any help you can offer is appreciated

```
            If lstFlavourChoices.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                MsgBox("You need to select a flavour from the list.")
            Else

                If lstFlavourChoices.SelectedIndex >= 2 Then
                    totalDue = totalDue + txtNumberOfScoops.Text * specialFlavours
                Else

                    totalDue = totalDue + txtNumberOfScoops.Text * standardFlavours

                    If chkNuts.Checked = True Then
                        totalDue = totalDue + 0.6
                        If chkWhippedCream.Checked = True Then
                            totalDue = totalDue + 0.8

                            If optNoToppings.Checked = True Then 'these statements will check to ensure the user has selected
                                totalDue = totalDue
                            ElseIf optOneTopping.Checked = True Then
                                totalDue = totalDue + COST_OF_TOPPING
                            ElseIf optTwoToppings.Checked = True Then
                                totalDue = totalDue + COST_OF_TOPPING * 2
                            ElseIf optThreeToppings.Checked = True Then
                                totalDue = totalDue + COST_OF_TOPPING * 3
                            Else
                                MsgBox("You must select a number of toppings")

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
                    End If
                End If



    lblTotalDue.Text = FormatCurrency(totalDue)
```

Comment: some of them should result in an `Exit Sub` and closing `End If`.  If they did not select an item in the list, for example.  There is no Else, it a case of *Get out of here*.

Comment: what about the other two if statements at the start, I added Exit sub but should they also have the end if instead of else?

Comment: You're only checking `optXTopping` when `chkNuts` and `chkWhippedCream` are checked. I'm guessing they should be independent?

Comment: Nuts and Toppings can only be calculated when it is a standard flavour.  Teh scoops/flavours calc should be a standalone If.  All the problems would be quite apparent if you set a breakpoint and stepped thru the code.

Comment: They should be independant, which is probably why when running it skips them. How can I rephrase it so that they won't be reliant on eachother?EDIT: figured it out and now its calculating correctly, not even sure how to set up breakpoints but now im off to youtube to do some more learning before I attempt any more projects. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @Ryan, it has to do with where the End If statement is.  Visual Studio indents the code so you can see what is controlled by the IF and Else statements.  For example, if the user does not select nuts (chkNuts.Checked = false) then all of the other tests are skipped.  Move the End If statements so that the nut check is completed before doing the whipped cream check.

Comment: It was explained in the comments to the other time you posted this question that you should *use the debugger*, and step through the code. It's pretty easy to see what's wrong if you do so, and in the process you'll learn a really important pair of skills (learning to read your code and how to use a debugger).